# Upload Kendo React PDF to Firebase storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, pdf, kendo-ui, pdf-generation

I am trying to upload a Kendo React PDF to Firebase storage. When I use Kendo's drawingDOM(), I get a CORS issue for an image

Kendo's savePDF() and PDFExport both result in the file saving to the desktop, and not being accessible to then use in another followup function. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Ended up making the image with the CORS issue base64 and using the following code to prevent saving to the desktop:

```
const doc = document.getElementById('doc')

let pdfOptions = {
    paperSize: 'Letter',
    subject: '',
    keywords: '',
    margin: "2cm",
    scale: 0.6
}

drawDOM(doc, pdfOptions)
        .then((group) => {
            console.log(group)
            return exportPDF(group, pdfOptions)
        })
        .then((data) => {
            var pdfData = data.split(';base64,')[1]

            // Upload to server
            const storageRef = INSERT_FIREBASE_STORAGE_REF
            const docFile = INSERT_FIREBASE_CHILD_PATH

            docFile.putString(pdfData, 'base64', {contentType:'application/pdf'})
                .then((snapshot) => {
                    docFile.getDownloadURL()
                        .then((url) => {
                            // Do other things
                        })
                })
        })
```